# permitindo apenas letras no input com jquery Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem como permitir apenas letras no input com o jquery Mask?

Estou usando esse plugin:
[JQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Na documentação diz isso: "A (Numbers and Letters), S (A-Za-z)". Então acho que no seu caso use o "S" como máscara de letras.

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo para mim?

Comment: Já foi postada uma resposta com exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#letras').mask('SSSS');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.8/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="letras">
```

De acordo com a [documentação](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/), você pode usar a letra `S` pra especificar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

```
'S': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/}
```

Comment: vle muito obrigado